# Universal Windows Platform in Windows Forms - GattCharacteristic events

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp

I managed to UWP code from Heart-rate-monitor-UWP example in my Windows Forms application

Basically, the code needed are those lines:
https://github.com/DrJukka/Heart-rate-monitor-UWP-/blob/master/HeartBeat/HeartBeat/MainPage.xaml.cs#L39

https://github.com/DrJukka/Heart-rate-monitor-UWP-/blob/master/HeartBeat/HeartBeat/Engine/HeartBeatEngine.cs#L109

what makes events to be fired gracefully.

I ported the code to Windows Forms app but events are not fired no matter what I try... I noted that in UWP app there is specific Bluetooth capability set in manifest file which is clearly what we don't have in the classic .NET app.

Already few days on it... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Before looking into the WinForm project, is the UWP app working on your device?

Comment: yes. it is daydream controller. it sends events beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

so the answer is that you need call CoInitializeSecurity before and this basically solves the problem :)

described here with full story
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/

Greg